# LINQ C# sql rank with case order by

Tags: c#, sql, linq, case, rank

I have some SQL which needs converting to c# LINQ, I've spent days looking at this with many failed attempts.

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN SMV >= TA 
    THEN RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TA - SMV) 
    ELSE RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SMV DESC) 
    END AS PRank
FROM blah
```

This is one of the failed attempts:
( the last where clause doesn't in any way fit in the case)

```cs
var q = from s in myData select 
    new { Station = s.Station, 
          PRank = (from o in myData where o.Smv >= s.TA
               select o).Count() + 1 
        };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you mind sharing some of the "many failed attempts"?

Comment: my latest attempt, however the last where clause doesnt in any way fit in the case.


var q = from s in groupByPackingStations
                 select new { 
                     PackingStation = s.PackingStation, 
                     PRank = (from o in groupByPackingStations

                             where DateTime.MinValue.AddMinutes( o.ChuteSmv + o.PackingSmv) >= s.TimeAvailableToPack || currentTime >= s.DespatchFrom
                             select o).Count() + 1 
                             
                 };

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.